# IIS - dotnetcore - App pool not starting for mixed mode application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

The app pool for a mixed-mode application (ASP.NET Core application targeting .NET full framework) is not starting in IIS. The WebAPI is configured as a reverse proxy to run out of process. 
Tried couple of things as below:

1. Installed Components

   - Hosting Bundle - DotNetCore.2.0.5-WindowsHosting.exe
   - ASP.NET Core Runtime & .NET Core Runtime - 2.0.5

I tried reinstalling all the components again. 
ASPNetCoreModule is proper in IIS.

- Reinstalled all the components again.
- Verified AspNetCoreModule in IIS
- Stdout logs are turned on but no log file created.
- Verfied Identity for app pool user and it is in the administrator user group.
- Event Viewer does not log any specific error. Below error is logged five times in Event Viewer. I know this is due to Rapid Fail protection, but not able to pinpoint the reason what is causing the process to crash.

> A process serving application pool
>   'App Pool Name' reported a failure during
>   application preloading or service loading. The process id was 'XXXX'.
>   Please ensure that all application preload or service settings in the
>   application pool are configured properly.  The data field contains the
>   error number.

Is there any other logging which can help why the process is crashing and not letting app pool to start.
All the App Pools with mixed-mode applications are not starting, so this must be an issue with any installation on the server. 
This was working previously until I installed ASP.NET core runtime shared framework 2.1.16 for some other application and uninstalled and then when I did a clean install of the dotnet core related installers.

Can there be any registry of something that can be causing some mismatch in the version.

Comment: I was able to get the app pool working when I installed the Hosting module, runtime all of v2.2. Still not sure about why the error with 2.0.5, as for the same application it was previously working with 2.0.5.

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 and 2.2 are both end-of-life, so I wonder why you are still trying to use them.

Comment: I'm uplifting it to 2.1 and that's why installed runtime for v2.1.16 to test few things. Once I uninstalled 2.1.16 it stopped working with 2.0.5 as well.